# Why do I get "Undefined index: mail en comment_form_validate()"?

Tags: comments, forms

Is there a way to fix the notice I get?

> Notice: Undefined index: mail en comment_form_validate()
>   Notice: Undefined index: homepage en comment_form_validate()

This appears in my message area with the errors for comments, only if I enable the development snapshot of the module to display errors or warnings (the configuration say I should turn this off in production), but I'm not sure if this is normal.

Should I ignore this? The default comment module doesn't display this bug, with or without the  development snapshot settings working. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Post up your custom code.  Seems like your using the wrong Language Selector.

Comment: Actually I do have some issues with the language, but I don't think this error has something to do with that. I have some suspects in my form_alter like: $form['author'], $form['actions']['submit'] = array( ). I can't place too much code in here... Actually you mentioned that I'm probably using a wrong language selector, I'm not using one at all. where should I place it ?

Comment: Do you get that error message for a module you are developing? If it is so, may you show the code you are using? Differently, it becomes hard to tell you why you are getting that error message.

Answer (score 1):

From your error messages it seems you are calling something like this

```
$form['field_name']['en'][0]['value']
```

Or something like that.  Which means the array key "en" is not available.  If you are not using languages, then I suggest using `LANGUAGE_NONE` as your key selector.

To prevent these types of messages you should perform an `isset` on the array element to make sure it exists before trying to retrieve a value from it.

Comment: I think the error message has been translated from Spanish, or other similar language where _on_ is translated with _en_. The user simply forgot to translate _en_. In fact, such error messages don't show two array indexes, but one. (The OP says to be from Panama; that would explain why the error message has been translated.)

Comment: I solve the problem. "It seems" it doesn't have to do with language. But I'm not sure why it need me to declare the array for user email and user homepage. $form['author']['homepage'] = array(... )  and $form['author']['mail']  = array(... ) I'm not printing this in my form, but it seems it need it for a complete saving of the comment. Thanks for point me in the right direction... The problem was in the FIELD_NAME it seems it was incomplete with that information.